# Scala: Recursively find max of array

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala. To practice recursion I set myself the task of finding the max value of an array. My base case is an array of length 1. For each recursive pass I'm comparing the sizes of the array values 0 and 1, eliminating the smaller value until the base case is met.

```
  def max(m: Array[Int]): Int = {
      if (m.length == 1) m(0)
      else if (m(0) > m(1)) m.take(1)
      else m.take(0)
    return max(m)
  }
```

However in the repl this returns nothing (presumably an infinite loop). I don't understand why the array doesn't reduce to length 1. Do I need a secondary inner function or something?

Comment: You could also define a local function that takes an element and a current-max. Then you call the local function again with the next element and an updated current-max.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely an infinite loop, as you are recursively calling `max` with the same argument you passed in (in the lingo, `take` is not a modifier).

To answer the rest of the question, you do not *need* an inner helper function.

Try to translate the following algorithm to Scala:

- If the list is empty, throw an error
- Else if the list has one element return its first element
- Else

  - (Recursively) compute the max of `m.take(1)`, call this `max_of_rest`
  - Return the larger of `m(0)` and `max_of_rest`

Have fun learning recursion in Scala!

**ADDENDUM**

The above algorithm, while it produces the correct answer, does so inefficiently. Consider:

```
maximum([2, 4, 1, 10, 3])
  = max(2, maximum([4, 1, 10, 3]))
  = max(2, max(4, maximum([1, 10, 3])))
  = max(2, max(4, max(1, maximum([10, 3]))))
  = max(2, max(4, max(1, max(10, maximum([3])))))
  = max(2, max(4, max(1, max(10, 3))))
  = max(2, max(4, max(1, 10)))
  = max(2, max(4, 10))
  = max(2, 10)
  = 10
```

Note how each of calls "pile up" on the call stack, consuming lots of extra memory. It is much better in this case to use a tail-recursive formulation.

```
maximum([2, 4, 1, 10, 3])
  = _maximum([4, 1, 10, 3], max(4, 2))
  = _maximum([1, 10, 3], max(1, 4))
  = _maximum([10, 3], max(10, 4))
  = _maximum([3], max(3, 10))
  = _maximum([], 10)
  = 10
```

Now in this tail-recursive case, as pointed out by Joost den Boer, you *do* have a second function. You can see that this inner recursive function works like this

```
_maximum(a, v) =
  if a is empty return v
  else return _maximum(a.take(1), max(a(0), v))
```

The outer function goes something like

```
maximum(a) =
  if a is empty raise an error
  else return _maximum(a.take(1), a(0))
```

I'm purposely not using Scala syntax so you can enjoy working it out. Have fun!

Comment: Great answer. However, to make the solution tail-recursive, which you should always try to opt for, an inner function is required IMHO.

Comment: Oh you're right of course! I will add the tail recursive formulation to the answer

Answer (score 2):

`m.take()` does not modify `m`. As a result you are calling `max(m)` with the very same array as an argument over and over.

```
scala> val m = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
m: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> m.take(1)
res0: Array[Int] = Array(1)

scala> m
res1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Also notice that `take()` does not do at all what you think it is doing.

```
scala> m.take(0)
res2: Array[Int] = Array()

scala> m.take(3)
res3: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```